# Google App Indexing not resolving for Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, cocoapods, google-app-indexing

I'm trying to integrate [Google App Indexing](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app) into my iOS / Swift app. I installed it [via CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAppIndexing). The problem is it's not resolving any of Google's code. Here's what I got:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    var sanitizedURL = GSDDeepLink.handleDeepLink(url)
    return true
}
```

The compile error says: `Use of unresolved identifier 'GSDDeepLink'`. I tried adding `import GoogleAppIndexing` and even `import GSDDeepLink`, but it says: `no such module 'GoogleAppIndexing'`. Any ideas or anyone got this to work with Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under supporting files, there should be a file that ends with "-Bridging-Header.h." You want to do the Objective-C import statement there:

```
#import <GoogleAppIndexing/GoogleAppIndexing.h>
```

Comment: I don't have a Bridging-Header file anywhere (I searched the whole workspace). I believe this is because CocoaPods is handling all this since I've never seen a bridging file for any Swift / CocoaPod project before.

Comment: create an objective-c header file, and make sure that you designate its path in the "swift compiler - code generation" section of your build settings under the setting "objective-c bridging header." you probably also want to set "install objective-c compatibility header" to yes